# How to change the owner and group of a directory by the name of that directory?

Tags: security, nginx, chown, wordpress, chgrp

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 Nginx server environment with several CMS (WordPress) websites under document root.

All the site directories have `www-data` as owner and group, recursively.

---

According to some security consultation I got, this is problematic because data from one site could alter any other adjacent site (for example, a malicious module installed in one the CMSs of one of the sites).

I assume that the solution would be to change this command which I always run after adding a new site (and also in cron after updates that change owner and group):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/*
```

To some conditional command that changes these characteristics not just to `www-data` but to the actual name of the site dir.

To clarify, the owner of each site dir should be `domain.tld` and the group should also be `domain.tld` (I always name site dirs as per the site's domain.tld).

What could be such a conditional command?

---

Note: The Nginx user as well as the dir `/var/www/html/` will both stay with `www-data:www-data`.

### Update for G-Man:

I have yet to test but I think this is good if you pass `${domain}` as the first argument for a variable (`$1`):

```
chown -R ${domain}:${domain} ${domain}/*
```

Though I'd keep it:

```
chown -R ${domain}:www-data ${domain}/*
```

Of course, `adduser ${domain} --disabled-password --disabled-login` is needed before, if wasn't done.

Comment: First I want to thank you for the answer and comment. Second, I've just edited the question to clarify what should be the end state.

Comment: By the way, I may be missing something, but I believe that changing the owner is at best a half solution to the security problem (if there really is one).  Data doesn’t alter data, *processes* alter data.  If the websites (can) include code (e.g., JavaScript or PHP?) that can run on your server, then you need to ensure that code from the `domain1` site ***runs** as* the `domain1` user.  Have you addressed that?

Comment: (1) ``${domain}:www-data`` is probably good enough if you use modes 644 and 755.  If you use 664 and 775, you need ``${domain}:${domain}``. (2) As I said, I may be missing something; I don’t know Nginx or CMS.  But I still don’t see anything that causes module(s) from the ``domain1`` site (directory tree) to execute as the ``domain1`` user.

Comment: Why does 775:644 and 755:644 require different owner:group set?

Comment: Because 644 and 755 give write access only to the owner (user), so having a distinct UserID is sufficient to protect the files of one domain from the actions of another; but 664 and 775 give write access to the owner and the group, so you need to have distinct UserIDs and GroupIDs to get separation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be missing something, but this looks simple:

```
$ cd /var/www/html
$ for dir in *
do
    chown -R "$dir:$dir" "$dir"
done
```

If you’re concerned about the correctness of these commands,
you can insert the word **`echo`** before `chown`, e.g.,

```
$ cd /var/www/html
$ for dir in *
do
    echo chown -R "$dir:$dir" "$dir"
done
```

to have it tell you what `chown` commands it is going to do,
without actually doing them. 
This trick applies throughout this answer,
and, in fact, to most shell script solutions (i.e., to other questions).

If you want to do it in one line,

```
$ cd /var/www/html  &&  for d in *; do chown -R "$d:$d" "$d"; done
```

---

I did the `cd` to avoid the complexity that [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/417297/80216#417309)

embraced. 
If you do

```
$ for dir in /var/www/html/*
```

then `dir` will be set to `/var/www/html/domain1`,
`/var/www/html/domain2`, `/var/www/html/domain3`, etc.,
which is fine for manipulating the directories,
but doesn’t give you the user and group names that you need for `chown`. 
The other answer uses a rather convoluted (and not entirely reliable)
`awk` procedure to separate the last level of the directory path
(i.e., the directory name, which is also the user name; e.g., `domain1`)
from the rest of the path. 
Fortunately, we can do the equivalent thing (but somewhat better)
entirely in the shell, like this:

```
$ for dir in /var/www/html/*
do
    owner="${dir##*/}"
    chown -R "$owner:$owner" "$dir"
done
```

The `${dir##*/}` is a special form of [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)
that takes the value of `$dir` and removes everything up through
(and including) the last `/` (slash) character. 
This, of course, leaves only the directory base *name*, i.e., the user name,
so we assign that to `owner` and use it in the `chown` command. 
Note that this code is [POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)
and should work in any POSIX-compliant shell;
unlike some of the answers on this site, it does not depend on bash.

If you want to do *this* in one line,

```
$ for d in /var/www/html/*; do o="${d##*/}"; chown -R "$o:$o" "$d"; done
```

---

Of course, if your concern is only that
you don’t want your main shell’s working directory to be changed,
then you can just do the first command in a subshell:

```
$ (cd /var/www/html  &&  for d in *; do chown -R "$d:$d" "$d"; done)
```

---

It goes without saying (but I’ll say it anyway)
that this requires that you have users (and groups)
named `domain1`, `domain2`, `domain3`, etc., defined
before you run any of these commands. 
If you have a script to add a new site,
it’s a simple matter to add a command to create a new user
whenever you make a new directory, before you run `chown`. 
If you do run `chown` with a name that is not a defined user name,
it will give you an `invalid user` error message.

Comment: Deep thanks! I can't test right now but without `cd` isn't good? `for dir in /${drt}/ do; chown -R "$dir:$dir" "$dir" done`.

Comment: I’m not sure exactly what you’re suggesting.  `for dir in /var/www/html` will set `dir` to `/var/www/html`, which doesn’t do you any good.  `for dir in /var/www/html/domain42` will set `dir` to `/var/www/html/domain42`, which is potentially useful — but if you’re going to process only one directory, you don’t need a loop. See the updated answer for more responses.

Comment: G-Man. I would appreciate your review for my update in the question. Does my approach look okay to you?